# Get the word around the insertion point - Tkinter Text

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to get the word the user's insertion point is "within". I've been trying multiple methods, such as my most recent being:

```py
insert_idx = TEXT_EDITOR.index(INSERT)
word_start_index = TEXT_EDITOR.search(r"\b", insert_idx, backwards=True, regexp=True)
    word_end_index = TEXT_EDITOR.search(r"\b", insert_idx, regexp=True)

    word = ""
    print(word_start_index, word_end_index)
    if word_start_index and word_end_index:
        word = TEXT_EDITOR.get(f"{word_start_index}", f"{word_end_index}")
```

And many other methods before, too. They all either gave errors or just didn't work.
I'm still learning Tkinter, so I don't know if there's a function that just does this, or if there's some obvious method I'm overlooking.

[image: Hello Stackover|flow]

So basically in the image above, the insertion point is in the word "Stackoverflow". More specifically, in between the r and f. Now, what I'm trying to do is figure out how to set the variable "word" to "Stackoverflow".

Comment: `TEXT_EDITOR.get("insert wordstart", "insert wordend")` should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper ! I did some experimenting with what you said, and found that `word = TEXT_EDITOR.get("insert -1c wordstart", "insert -1c wordend")` is exactly what I needed! Again, thanks so much.

Comment: "They all either gave errors or just didn't work." - **Exactly what happens** when you try them, and **how is that different** from the requirement? How do they not work - what is wrong with the result? What errors do you get, and what did they tell you about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text index allows for modifiers to an index. Two such modifiers are `wordstart` and `wordend`. So, to get the start and end of the word at the insertion point you can use `"insert wordstart"` and `"insert wordend"`.

These modifiers are defined as follows:

*?submodifier?* **wordstart** - Adjust the index to refer to the first character of the word containing the current index. A word consists of any number of adjacent characters that are letters, digits, or underscores, or a single character that is not one of these. If the **display** submodifier is given, this only examines non-elided characters, otherwise all characters (elided or not) are examined.

*?submodifier?* **wordend** - Adjust the index to refer to the character just after the last one of the word containing the current index. If the current index refers to the last character of the text then it is not modified. If the **display** submodifier is given, this only examines non-elided characters, otherwise all characters (elided or not) are examined.

[docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.html#M41)